# nodejs square cube evaluator throwing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, websocket, cube

A client is connected to a nodejs hosted [cube evaluator](https://github.com/square/cube) using websockets.

When the limit is set to anything over 900 the server blows up with the following error:

```
// Copyright Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors.
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The code was copied straight from the websites [getting started guide I.e.](https://github.com/square/cube/wiki/Evaluator)

### Client

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://nodeserver/1.0/event/get");

socket.onopen = startReceiving;

function startReceiving() {
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    var startDate = yesterday.getTime();

            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "expression": "some_event(param1,param2,param3,param4).eq(param1,'SomeValue')",
                "start": startDate,
                limit: 20000
            }));

            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "expression": "someother_event(param1,param2,param3,param4).eq(param1,'SomeOtherValue')",
                "start": startDate,
                limit: 20000
            }));

}

socket.onmessage = function (message) {
    var event = JSON.parse(message.data);
    // Do something with event
};
```

### Server

```
var cube = require("cube");
var appConfig = require('./server.config.js');

var evaluatorOptions = appConfig.evaluatorOptions;

var registerServer = function(options, cubeSubject) {
    var server = cube.server(options);
    server.register = function(db, endpoints) {
        cubeSubject.register(db, endpoints);
    };
    server.start();
};

registerServer(evaluatorOptions, cube.evaluator);
```

Can anyone suggests what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the latest version of the cube library solved the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the recursion was caused by a **rollopJoin** that was referenced in its own **rollups** array.

```
myCombinedRollup: {
    type: `rollupJoin`,
    rollups: [ OtherCube.someRollup, CUBE.myCombinedRollup ],
    //...
}
```

Once I changed it to reference another rollup, I got a different error :)

```
myCombinedRollup: {
    type: `rollupJoin`,
    rollups: [ OtherCube.someRollup, CUBE.differentRollup ],
    //...
}
```